# Show Image instead of Button-Frame with CSS/Java

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, web

i have following Code in my jsp.

```
#LoginButton
        {
            margin-left: 760px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            background: url(Images/Login.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
            border: 0;
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
            heigth: 62px;
        }
```

and further below

```
<div id="LoginButton"><input type ="submit" name="Log" id="Log" value="LogIn"></div>
```

i want to just see the picture without the Button, but it seems with that code i saw on various questions and sites the image is really in the background of the button and not "instead" of the button.

A pure image type button would work perfectly, but then i can't submit a value to the doPost Method of my Servlet and i need the submit to the doPost Method with the value "LogIn".

What am i doing wrong? Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `type` attribute of the `input` element to "image", like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/yeu6yo70/

Comment: Already tried that, but then i have The problem that The value i set "Login" is Not submitted but i need that value to be submitted to The doPost method to continue